# Sharing the variables between the actions in the controller in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a module where I have to take the consent of the user to save the set of records.

those set of records are created in an action, which has to be made available in another action of the same controller,  the records are being saved by the user consent.

now I can send these set of records to UI, from UI to again controller, if the user continues to save, if not cancel.

Problem is there will be thousands of records, which is painful to carry between UI and controller so My plan is to  make the set of records available to the action which is being called by the continue button

the code

```
 def create 
               @valid_members = generate_member_upload_results(params[:member_upload_user][:members_list])
 end
```

in this action @valid_members is going to have the set of records. after this action executes in UI we will ask user whether the records are to be saved if no then cancels  if yes  then the  following action will  takes palce

```
def create_member
 count = 0 
    unless @valid_members.blank?
      @valid_members.each do |m| 
        count = count + 1
        m.save(:validate => false)
      end
    end
     redirect_to :back , notice:'#{count} members records created'
  end
```

I want my @valid member should the same object which I used in create def.

Comment: rails and http in general are stateless, that means between actions all information is lost. i would probably send params[:member_upload_user][:members_list] to create_member and calculate it there again, or send create_member @valid_members as an extra param

Comment: thanks for the response. 'generate_member_upload_results' this is doing a job like reading spreadsheet and extracting the records validating the users and filtering them and params[:member_upload_user][:members_list] is an xlsx file so its hard to re run the def generate_member_upload_results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure this is feasible with the flow you're suggesting. This sounds like something that could be resolved with a [multi-step form](https://www.codewithjason.com/rails-multi-step-forms/) but you would need to pass the data across or temporarily store it, which is seemingly what you're trying to avoid.

Alternatively, can you create a Rails endpoint that services the first step via javascript directly from the frontend? That can return the data without the user leaving the page, they can then confirm they are happy and submit the page once with approval.